# set the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Header in Response

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to use Cookie along with the go-endpoints.

For this purpose , it is necessary to set the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials to Header.

However , do not know how to set the Allow-Credentials to Header in go-endpoints.

allowCookieAuth is , How do I to true doing ?

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/go-endpoints/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=allowCookieAuth

because there is no http.ResponseWriter the go-endpoints handler , it is not possible to set the Http Header.

```
func (gs *GreetingService) List(c endpoints.Context, r *GreetingsListReq) (*GreetingsList, error) {
    if r.Limit <= 0 {
        r.Limit = 10
    }

    q := datastore.NewQuery("Greeting").Limit(r.Limit)
    greets := make([]*Greeting, 0, r.Limit)
    keys, err := q.GetAll(c, &greets)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for i, k := range keys {
        greets[i].Key = k
    }
    return &GreetingsList{greets}, nil
}
```

help me!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then all you have to do is something like:

```
func yourHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    // ...other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By patching the go-endpoints, and reached the goal .

```
dst.Auth = &struct {
        AllowCookie bool `json:"allowCookieAuth"`
    }{true}
```

https://github.com/sinmetal/go-endpoints/commit/25c0e85b06c13511291cb8b54f2878c5ac4587ad

However , I do not think that's very good way .
If possible , I want to reach the goal without patching .